# Rails 3.2.8 Routing Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

Started learning Rails a couple of hours back using the book Agile Web Development with Rails and hit a roadblock straightaway.

Created a controller called Say using:
`rails generate controller Say hello goodbye`

Then I was trying to hit the URL `http://localhost:3000/Say/hello` but it says:

`No route matches [GET] "/Say/hello"`

My routes.rb looks alright too (at least from what the other answers on the same question say):

```
Demo::Application.routes.draw do
  get "say/hello"

  get "say/goodbye"
end
```

Any help? Just not able to figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a capitalization error.  Can you go to

```
http://localhost:3000/say/hello
```

Lowercase s in say

Answer (score 1):

It's case-sensitive. 
Try to reach it at `http://localhost:3000/say/hello`

Comment: Run pls `rake routes` at console and show us what it's giving.

Comment: `say_hello GET /say/hello(.:format)   say#hello
say_goodbye GET /say/goodbye(.:format) say#goodbye`

Comment: I checked on my environment. It works just fine. Try to check your previous steps in rails setup.